# Inquiry about Using Google Sheets with Highcharts and Service Account

Tags: highcharts

I am currently working on a project where I use Highcharts for data visualization, and I'm facing a challenge regarding the integration with Google Sheets with a service account.

Highcharts GPT mentions a googleServiceAccount option for data configurations, as follows:

```
data: {
  googleSpreadsheetKey: "your_google_spreadsheet_key",
  googleServiceAccount: {
    client_email: "your_service_account_email@example.com",
    private_key: "your_service_account_private_key"
  }
}
```

However, the googleServiceAccount property does not seem to be recognized in the expected data types for Highcharts. The primary goal is to secure access to my Google Sheet by using a service account instead of a public API key.

My questions are as follows:

1. Is it currently possible to use a service account with Highcharts for private Google Sheets?
2. If not, is there any planned development or feature update that would enable the use of service accounts in this context?

Thank you for your help,

Comment: Currently, it is only possible to use data from public Google Spreadsheets in Highcharts as in the follow demo example https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/data/google-spreadsheet/. As a workaround, you can attempt to implement the solution described on our Highcharts forum using OAuth: https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=51579#p189366

If in your opinion this functionality should be integrated, please submit a feature request on our GitHub page: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/new/choose